# Using two items in a list in a loop

Tags: r

I have a list of dates and i'm trying to assign one date to a variable, and the previous date in the list to another.

I can seem to find a way to assign the previous day.  I'd hoped this would work:

```
list = c("20200102", "20200103", "20200106", "20200107", "20200108", 
"20200109")


for(i in 1:length(list))
 {
 date = list[i]
 date1 = list[i]-1
 }
```

but I get an obvious non-numeric error with date1

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you meant `as.Date`

Comment: no - i'm using it as a string to find a file name

Comment: `as.character` doesn't have the second option for `format`.  can you show your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need a loop here. If it needs to remain in the original format, after subtracting 1 from the `Date` class converted variable, apply `format`

```
v1 <- list
v2 <- format(as.Date(list, "%Y%m%d")-1, "%Y%m%d")
```

---

If we need a loop, we can use `lapply` without any need for preassignment

```
lapply(seq_along(list)), function(i) {
       date <- as.character(as.Date(list[i], "%Y%m%d"))
       date1 <- as.character(as.Date(list[i], "%Y%m%d") - 1)
  })
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a loop that reads in a value from one file (date) and a value from the previous date (date1).  There must be a way to do this in one go rather than storing the values?

Comment: @nicshah your loop in the post is not clear to me.  Please update your post with a small reproducible example

Comment: I would like to see various solutions and like the style of your answer. Let’s keep open and friendly:)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding sure. have a great. day!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your expected output, and below is my guess regarding your intended `for` loop code

```
date <- c()
date1 <- c()
for(i in 1:length(list))
{
  date[i] = as.character(as.Date(list[i], "%Y%m%d"))
  date1[i] = as.character(as.Date(list[i], "%Y%m%d")-1)
}
```

such that

```
> date
[1] "2020-01-02" "2020-01-03" "2020-01-06" "2020-01-07" "2020-01-08"
[6] "2020-01-09"

> date1
[1] "2020-01-01" "2020-01-02" "2020-01-05" "2020-01-06" "2020-01-07"
[6] "2020-01-08"
```

In that case, actually you don't even need `for` loop, i.e.,

```
date <- as.Date(list,"%Y%m%d")
date1 <- as.Date(list,"%Y%m%d")-1)
```

Comment: @akrun OP wants the previous date... yours just gives the elements before, but mine gives the day before. You run and compare and will see the difference